# Tengo una tabla "Personal" con las columna "ID" y "DATOS". donde ID tiene varios datos y quiero crear otra tabla donde este agrupado por ID lso datos

Tags: mysql

Lo que necesito es poder pasar la tabla "Personal" donde hay 2 columnas "ID" y "DATOS" donde el ID puede estar repetido y tengo que juntar los datos de "DATOS" por cada ID. y Crear una tabla nueva con todos los datos.

ACTUAL:

| ID | DATOS |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | Hola soy A |
| 05 | HOla soy cinco 1 |
| 05 | soy Cinco 2 |
| 05 | soy cinco 3 |
| 03 | soy tres |

Cómo debería quedar:

| ID | DATOS |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | Hola soy A |
| 05 | HOla soy cinco 1 soy Cinco 2 soy cinco 3 |
| 03 | soy tres |

Necesito que después que me muestre el resultado, poder guardarlo en una tabla, ya con los ID que no se repitan.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y muestra qué has intentado hasta el momento. Lee [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que agrupar por id y utilizar la función `GROUP_CONCAT` de MySQL para agrupar los datos que corresponden al mismo id:

`SEPARATOR`: define como se van a separar los datos agrupados (en este caso utlizando un espacio), por defecto es una coma.

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(datos SEPARATOR ' ')
FROM personal
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id;
```

Para insertar los datos agrupados en otra tabla (personal_2):

```
INSERT INTO personal_2 (id, datos)

SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(datos SEPARATOR ' ')
FROM personal
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: Por default el orden es por el grupo, así que -en este caso- realmente no es necesario el ORDER BY.

Comment: el order by en un insert no hace absolutamente nada...

Answer (score 0):

gracias a todos lo pude solucionar de la siguiente manera:

```
'SELECT ID,GROUP_CONCAT(DATOS SEPARATOR  " "),FECREG
```

FROM base08
GROUP BY ID, FECREG
ORDER BY ID, FECREG ASC') as $row) {

}
Gracias